# How to change language using a spinner kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I change the app's language when the user selects it from a spinner

Comment: follow this link for change app language in kotlin: https://medium.com/@wojciech_jeziorski/android-change-the-app-language-programmatically-with-kotlin-7687b095788c

Comment: anymway, I suggest you to have app language same to device language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android

Comment: i'll check thanks